# Apollo Client Introspective Queries

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, apollo-boost

#### Works on the Playground...

I am trying to query the following enum values:

```
query {
  __type(name:"ActivityType") {
    enumValues {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

When I test the query with the playground, it works. I receive a list of the enumeration values for the `ActivityType`:

#### Doesn't work with Apollo-Client...

When I run the following code with the client, I receive the expected results for the first query, but not for the second:

```
import ApolloClient, { gql } from 'apollo-boost'

const FIRST_QUERY = gql`
  query successfulQuery {
    totalActivities
  }
`

const SECOND_QUERY = gql`
  query unsuccessfulQuery {
    __type(name:"ActivityType") {
      enumValues {
        name
      }
    }
  }
`

const client = new ApolloClient({ uri: 'http://localhost:4000' })

//
// First Query returns data
//

client.query({ query: FIRST_QUERY })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)

//
// Second Query does not return data
//

client.query({ query: SECOND_QUERY })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
```

The results

```
{ data: {...}, loading: false, networkStatus: 7, stale: false }
{ data: null, loading: false, networkStatus: 7, stale: false }
```

Is there something special that you have to implement with the client to allow introspective queries?

Comment: Are any errors coming back in the GraphQL response?  Are you running the server in production mode?

Comment: No errors. The data object just comes back null. The above is the full payload. I don't think the Apollo-Server is in production mode? We're able to run the introspective query from the playground and curl.